# Strange CSS brief flashing divs / images issue

Tags: css, css-animations, cloudflare

I have a website that recently started to have an issue with a bunch of divs containing links and images are flashing at the top of the website momentarily while the page loads.

See: pelicancases.com

It's strange because I see those images already rendered even before the images flash. Also, this is a new occurrence.

Could this possibly be due to CSS animation or CloudFlare caching/optimization?

Any recommendations on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: First thing I noticed is that it loads slow so any yet unloaded images will display the alt text. For example the img with class "igWelcomeFlagHeader" (country flag) displays the alternative text which is on multiple lines because of the img size.
The second thing is when the alt text is smaller than the img like in "ctl00_ctl00_NestedMaster_PageHeader_StoreHeader_H_StoreLogo1_Logo" img.
The second thing I noticed is that you are using a custom font (FontAwesome) - like the one displaying the top menu arrows which loads slow. You need to make divs which are big as the images and put them in.

Comment: Your <a> tags are loading in there for some reason before the page fully renders.

Answer (score 0):

If I use [WebPageTest](https://www.webpagetest.org/)  to inspect your page I see some browser related issues.

When testing with Chrome there are three 404s
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160921_2N_1GQS/

http://www.pelicancases.com/android-chrome-192x192.png
http://www.pelicancases.com/favicon-96x96.png
http://www.pelicancases.com/favicon-194x194.png

If I test with IE 11 I don't see any 404s
https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160921_TE_1H77/

To troubleshoot I would start by disabling CloudFlare caching
(Domain > Overview > Development Mode > Enabled)

Then fix the 404s, they may not be the cause of the problem but worth eliminating first.

If you still have the flashing, try and figure out if it's browser related.

Good luck!